# simple_form add order using label_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Using the `simple_form gem`, I've a form with the following field:

`f.association :company, label_method: :company_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: false`

How can I sort the resulting array by a attribute, like `:name`? The docs only mention using order for another case, using `collection: ...`. Just adding `order: :name` to my input doesn't work.

Is this possible at all? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the ordering of the `collection` items like this:

```
f.association :company, collection: Company.all.order(:name), label_method: :name, value_method: :id
```

I don't think there is another way to sort the displayed items, you have to use `collection`.

Comment: Ok, but how can I then control what the labels in the dropdown show? (The reason I use `label_method`.)

Comment: I think you can just add those properties. Will update answer.

Comment: `f.association :company, collection: Company.all.order(:name).pluck(:name, :id)`